# how to keep my docker container up running?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-machine

I'm running all my application code inside a docker container and I'm using Jenkins to build. So it takes 2 to 3 hours to run the build and it creates the zip files inside the docker container and I'm copying that zip files to the server. So once the files are copied then the docker container is exited. I want that docker container to the used for the next build, if not, its going to download all the dependencies again and it takes another 2 to 3 hours to get the latest zip files created. Ultimately I want to use the cache of the dependencies which are downloaded after the first build

Comment: https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/docker-jenkins-data-persists

Answer (score 1):

You should either use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) or a local mirror/cache/proxy.

`-v /src/downloads:/downloads`